# Will using delete[] like this end in a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm sure this has been asked before, but the search terms are failing me for my specific situation.
Essentially, I'm creating a 2D tile engine. For overall efficiency and  to reduce a bit of overhead, I have decided to implement my own simple memory management container...

The following code is what I'm using to do so:

**`Tile.h`:**

```
//Tile class
class CTile
{
public:
    CTile();
    ~CTile();
    unsigned int row;
    unsigned int column;
};

//Container class
class CTileLayer
{
public:
    CTileLayer(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nCols, float w, float h);
    ~CTileLayer();

protected:
    CTile** m_tiles;
    unsigned long count;

    void Allocate(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nCols, float w, float h);
    void Free();
};
```

**`Tile.cpp`:**

```
#include "Tile.h"


CTile::CTile() : row(0), column(0)
{
}

CTile::~CTile()
{
}


CTileLayer::CTileLayer(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nCols, float w, float h) : m_tiles(NULL)
{
    Allocate(nRows, nCols, w, h);
}

CTileLayer::~CTileLayer()
{
    if(m_tiles != NULL) Free();
}

void CTileLayer::Allocate(unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nCols, float w, float h)
{
    unsigned int column = 0, row = 0;

    if(m_tiles != NULL) Free();
    m_tiles = new CTile*[count = (nRows * nCols)];

    for( unsigned long l = 0; l < count; l++ ) {
        m_tiles[l] = new CTile[count];
        m_tiles[l]->column = column + 1;
        m_tiles[l]->row = row + 1;
        //
        //...
        //
        if(++column > nCols) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }
}

void CTileLayer::Free()
{
    delete [] *m_tiles;
    delete [] m_tiles;
    m_tiles = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
```

So by seeing how each tile is allocated/freed, is it safe to say this won't produce any memory leaks?

If it will, what would be the most appropriate way to free this array, while making sure each object's destructor gets called? Should I loop through the array, manually deleting each object instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
CTile* m_tiles;

m_tiles = new CTile[nRows*nColumns];

delete[] m_tiles;
```

Comment: `&m_tiles[i]` or `m_tiles + i` gives you a pointer. Since new and delete are very expensive, this would greatly improve performance

Comment: Yes, I retracted my comment after realizing I misread your answer.
This should work just fine, and after a quick `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` I saw no leaks. Guess I was just overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 2):

You called `new CTile[count]` count times, once for each `m_tiles[l]`.

You need to therefore call `delete[]` count times, for each `m_tiles[l]`.

---

It isn't clear what `count` is good for, however.  You should be using `nRows` and `nColumns` for the two layers of the array.  Right now you have `nRows * nRows * nColumns * nColumns` instances of `CTile` allocated, which is probably too many.

Instead try

```
m_tiles = new CTile*[nRows];
```

```
m_tiles[l] = new CTile[nColumns];
```